# Nivo Slider Fails to Show 3rd Image in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slider, nivo-slider

The page in question can be viewed here: http://quiltersrule.com/beta/index.html and of course just use chrome to view the code.

I noticed that 80% of the time, my 3rd slider image just plain doesn't show. The slider just collapses until it moves onto my placeholder image #4. I have no idea what is going on. The image is the same size as the others, and I don't suspect a loading-time issue.

This only seems to happen in Chrome. I have not tried FF, and it does not happen in IE.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue in Chrome 29 beta, and no offense but the site looks really ugly, I hope that's not the final design, also why are you using `1400px` as your container width? there's only a small percentage of users with a screen that big http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

Comment: Everyone I have had take a look at it has said it doesn't work. I can't get it to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the transition type and it seems to work now.